# Iterating over dictionaries containing tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary, the values of which are tuples. I want to be able to iterate over the key and every individual element in the value tuple, rather than the tuple object itself.  Here's my code:

```
keys = ['a','b','c']
values = [(0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8)]
mydict = dict(zip(keys,values))
```

Now at this point, I'd like to do something like the following:

```
for key,num1,num2,num3 in mydict.iteritems():
    print key,num1,num2,num3
```

It turns out that I can only pull out the tuple value itself, not the individual elements.  How would I be able to iterate over each element of the tuple?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> for key, (num1, num2, num3) in mydict.iteritems():
...     print key, num1, num2, num3
... 
a 0 1 2
c 6 7 8
b 3 4 5
```

Using parens allows you to unpack the values.